# Find Hilbert polynomials of some projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Find the Hilbert polynomials of

- Veronese image $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n)$,
- $\mathbb{V}(F)$, where $F\in k[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$ is a homogeneous irreducible polynomial of degree $d$.

I know how to compute the Hilbert functions, but how to find the Hilbert polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the Hilbert function of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not hard to see. If $S=k[x_0,...x_n]$ is the graded polynomial ring in $n+1$ variables, then $$\dim_k S_t = \binom{n+t}{t}.$$ If you expand this formally, note $$\dim_k S_t = \frac{(t+n)\cdots (t+1)}{n!} = \frac{t^n}{n!} + \cdots$$ which is a polynomial in $t$, so this must be the Hilbert polynomial since it agrees with the Hilbert function when evaluated on integers. I'll let you figure out how the Veronese embedding changes this.

Now suppose you have a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ and $M = S/(f)$ is the homogeneous coordinate ring. Then there is an exact sequence of $S_0$-modules:
$$0 \to S_{t-d} \overset{\times f}{\longrightarrow} S_t \to M_t \to 0.$$ Now the Hilbert function is precisely $\dim_k M_t = \dim S_t - \dim_k S_{t-d}$. I'll leave it to you to compute this since I've already given you the Hilbert polynomial for $S$.